# Linux Gif Generating Issue Video To Animated Gif Generating Using FFMPEG

Tags: php, ffmpeg, gif, animated-gif, shell-exec

**I'm trying to create Animated Gif from video**.

My code works on Windows OS but when I put it on Linux/ Ubuntu hosting then it is not Working well.

```
<?php
$ffmpeg = "include/ffmpeg";                             
$Get_From_duration = 3.0;                               
$Duration_of_anime = 3.0;       
$InputvideoFile = "test.mp4";
$thumbname = "testgif";
$size = "320:180";      
$filter = "\"[0:v] fps=12,\"scale=$size:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=$size:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2\",split [a][b];[a] palettegen [p];[b][p] paletteuse\"";
$outimageFileG = "/".$thumbname.".gif";
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -ss $Get_From_duration -t $Duration_of_anime -i $InputvideoFile -filter_complex $filter $outimageFileG";
shell_exec($cmd);   
?>
```

I'm using FFMPEG `https://ffbinaries.com/downloads` Using `ffmpeg 4.2 binaries` Linux-64.

I have not found any error log! I'm confused.

Comment: @Mickael Leger Hi Sir Thanks For Editing My Question.

Comment: You need to narrow down the issue. Is the problem with your ffmpeg command or your PHP script? Did you run the same ffmpeg command manually, unscripted in a command line interface before trying to script it? Does ffmpeg even get executed? No errors at all? Add `-report` to your ffmpeg command and it will output a very verbose log file in the current directory.

Comment: Is this also your question? [FFmpeg code that is working on Windows but not working on Linux hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375766/ffmpeg-code-that-is-working-on-windows-but-not-working-on-linux-hosting)